# Join a row from another table to row in another table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following query for retrieving a list of items from database

```
    $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM diamondsList WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat AND cut IN(' . $cut . ') AND clarity IN ('.$clarity.') AND color IN ('. $color.') AND diamondsType IN (' . $type.') ');
```

diamondsList contains dealerId

I want to add dealer table with `diamondsList` i-e `diamondsList->dealer`. After searching i have found that JOIN is used but not sure How to use it to get dealer row from `diamondList->dealerId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like ...

```
SELECT diamondsList.*, 
dealer.name
FROM diamondsList
JOIN dealer
on diamondsList.dealerid = dealer.dealerid
WHERE .....
```

Comment: i want to add another field inside diamondList object [dealer] , i don't understand the use of dealer.name

Comment: dealer.name would include a field called name from your dealer table in your result set,  you could add other fields from the dealer table in the same way

Comment: I actually want to select Entire ROW from table dealers into diamondList object. e.g diamond->dealer = entire row from dealers table depending upload diamond-dealerId

Comment: you can try dealer.*, but depending on your column names you may have issues with duplicate field names for dealerid

Comment: JUST one thing, it is apending dealers row with diamondsList row. How can i definitely set diadmond['dealer'] = dealer Row.